# To teach my safe to swim? Google translate fails?

Tags: traducción, modismos

> Qué playa tan hermosa para enseñar a nadar a mi segura.

¿Qué significa la palabra "mi segura"?  ¿Significa noivio/novia?

[image: What is the meaning?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong reading, it's not *segura* but **suegra**: *mother-in-law*.

> What a nice beach to teach my mother-in-law how to swim

Comment: Ok.  Now this makes sense!  LOL